# How can we get list of parameters & variables and their default values of a scheduled SQL job?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I went through all the column of following query and each tables:

```
***SELECT * FROM 
[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[servers] AS [sSVR]
    ON [sJOB].[originating_server_id] = [sSVR].[server_id]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] AS [sCAT]
    ON [sJOB].[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sJSTP]
    ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJSTP].[job_id]
    AND [sJOB].[start_step_id] = [sJSTP].[step_id]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[database_principals] AS [sDBP]
    ON [sJOB].[owner_sid] = [sDBP].[sid]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] AS [sJOBSCH]
    ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules] AS [sSCH]
    ON [sJOBSCH].[schedule_id] = [sSCH].[schedule_id]***
```

I did't get any information regarding the parameters & variables and their default values used in the scheduled job.

I got a column "Command", in which I can see the arguments passed for that job, but it is not correct for all the jobs. 
Basically, I need to get the list of parameters of all the scheduled SQL jobs and list of variables created/used inside the packages of those jobs.
How can I get that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Command" is not correct?  Do you have an example of where the value of Command in the table isn't the same as in the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this programmatically or with a query.

The column "Command" that you mentioned, contains all the parameters and their values that are stored in the job-step configuration.  I don't know why you say it's "not correct", because I assure you it is.  It's presumably just not what you expect it to be for some unknown reason.

That column is as granular as the storage gets.   There is no table that holds the individual parameters and values in separate columns.  The only place those are stored is in the command column.

To see this, script your job is SSMS, scroll through the steps and find the command line, which will look something like this:

```
@command=N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\ODS\Marketing\ImportCalls.dtsx\"" /SERVER s1wdvsqlssis2 /Par "\"MyParameterName\"";"\"MyParameterValue\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E',
```

The command value should look like what you see in the command column in the jobsteps table.